# sharing database .mdb file over LAN

Tags: database, ms-access, networking, sharing, lan

I have a desktop application using Microsoft access database, its(PC) already connected with LAN(home network, small LAN) sharing data with full access control. Now i want to share this application with another Network(Large Network) and the user wants get the live updates, only need Read permission.user wants to query the database, want to retrieve the data for reading. how its possible? is it possible to share database only.?
Thanks advance..

Comment: not programming related

Comment: Is this a split database? If not, I HIGHLY recommend it. What you would need to do is place the backend (or your database) on a shared drive between the networks. If Group A can get to the database but Group B can't see it, how will they receive 'live updates'? They would be utilizing a totally separate database. With a split database, you can place the backend on one location and distribute the front end to serve this exact purpose. If multiple users are using the same database, things can get tricky with locks/corruption.

Comment: can you explain..? i didnt get..I am fresher. its not split, and now  multiple users using  with full permission. and splitting

Comment: @ #overmind.. can you explain..am newbie..

Answer (score 0):

I would run the User Level Security Wizard which simplifies the setup of user-level security. I would keep the MDB (or ACCDB) file where it is, and only give the new user (on the larger network) the account you have created with the wizard. This account can be set to have read only permissions.

Here is an article that should get you started.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/overview-of-access-security-mdb-HP005188226.aspx

Comment: Access User Level Security has been depreciated since Access 2007. While with 2007 and beyond you can use ULS with a mdb file, you cannot use ULS with a newer accDB format. So accDB does not support ULS, only that of the older mdb format.